# Converting undefined to object in Javascript error

Tags: javascript, undefined

Here are 3 functions: MakeNPC, CreateNPC and NPCAI. CreateNPC runs once at start up and sends data to MakeNPC so they show up in game. NPCAI runs every second and makes the NPC move in game. When CreateNPC calls MakeNPC everything is OK. Problem is that when the MakeNPC function gets a call from NPCAI an error occurs: can't convert undefined to object.

Line in which the error is reported by Firebug to come up is in first line of MakeNPC:

```
 Previous_bead_NPC[NPCid][0] = x;
```

Here is the whole code of these 3 functions. I wasted whole day trying to solve this and I'm about to cry myself to sleep any minute:(

```
var Previous_bead_NPC = new Array(10);
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Previous_bead_NPC[i] = new Array(7);
};

var NPC = new Array(10);
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    NPC[i] = new Array(7);

};





var MakeNPC = function (x, y, c, g, NPCid, dx, dy, s) 
{
"use strict";
    Previous_bead_NPC[NPCid][0] = x;
    Previous_bead_NPC[NPCid][1] = y;
    Previous_bead_NPC[NPCid][2] = PS.BeadColor(x, y);
    Previous_bead_NPC[NPCid][3] = PS.BeadGlyph(x, y);

    PS.BeadColor(x, y, c);
    PS.BeadData(x, y, "blocked");
    PS.BeadGlyph(x, y, g);  

    NPC[NPCid][0] = x; //x
    NPC[NPCid][1] = y; //y
    NPC[NPCid][2] = c; //color
    NPC[NPCid][3] = g; //glyph
    NPC[NPCid][4] = dx; //destination x
    NPC[NPCid][5] = dy; //destination y
    NPC[NPCid][6] = s; //status - 0: arrived, 1: en route
};

var CreateNPC = function ()
{
"use strict";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var x = PS.Random (30);
    var y = PS.Random (30);
    var c = COLOR.human;
    var g = " ";

    var r = PS.Random (100);

    if (r < 50)
    {
        c = COLOR.human;
    }
        else if (r < 75)
            {
                c = COLOR.nigro;
            }
            else 
                {
                    c = COLOR.asian;
                }

    r = PS.Random (19);
    g = letters[r];

    while (PS.BeadData(x, y) === "blocked")
    {
        x = PS.Random (30);
        y = PS.Random (30);
    }

    MakeNPC(x, y, c, g, i, x, y, 0);
}
};

// NPC pathfinding
var NPCAI = function(NPCid)
{
"use strict";
//choosing destination for NPC  
if (NPC[NPCid][6] == 0)
{
    var r = PS.Random (100);

    if (r < 10)
    {
        NPC[NPCid][4] = locations[0][0];
        NPC[NPCid][5] = locations[0][1];
    }
    else if (r < 20)
        {
            NPC[NPCid][4] = locations[1][0];
            NPC[NPCid][5] = locations[1][1];
        }
        else if (r < 30)
            {
                NPC[NPCid][4] = locations[2][0];
                NPC[NPCid][5] = locations[2][1];
            }
            else if (r < 40)
                {       
                    NPC[NPCid][4] = locations[3][0];
                    NPC[NPCid][5] = locations[3][1];
                }
                else if (r < 50)
                    {           
                        NPC[NPCid][4] = locations[4][0];
                        NPC[NPCid][5] = locations[4][1];
                    }
                    else if (r < 60)
                        {           
                            NPC[NPCid][4] = locations[5][0];
                            NPC[NPCid][5] = locations[5][1];
                        }
                            else if (r < 70)
                            {           
                                NPC[NPCid][4] = locations[6][0];
                                NPC[NPCid][5] = locations[6][1];
                            }
                                else if (r < 80)
                                {           
                                    NPC[NPCid][4] = locations[7][0];
                                    NPC[NPCid][5] = locations[7][1];
                                }
                                    else if (r < 90)
                                    {               
                                        NPC[NPCid][4] = locations[8][0];
                                        NPC[NPCid][5] = locations[8][1];
                                    }
                                        else if (r < 100)
                                        {                   
                                            NPC[NPCid][4] = locations[9][0];
                                            NPC[NPCid][5] = locations[9][1];
                                        }

    //checking if NPC isn't already at its destination
    if (NPC[NPCid][4] == NPC[NPCid][0] && NPC[NPCid][5] == NPC[NPCid][1])
    {
        NPC[NPCid][6] = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        NPC[NPCid][6] = 1;
    }
}

//pathfinding logic
if (NPC[NPCid][6] == 1)
{

    var pointAx = NPC[NPCid][0]; //current position x
    var pointAy = NPC[NPCid][1]; //current position y

    var pointBx = NPC[NPCid][4]; //destination x 
    var pointBy = NPC[NPCid][5]; //destination y

    var adjacent_squareNx = pointAx; 
    var adjacent_squareNy = pointAy - 1;

    var adjacent_squareEx = pointAx + 1; 
    var adjacent_squareEy = pointAy;

    var adjacent_squareSx = pointAx; 
    var adjacent_squareSy = pointAy + 1;

    var adjacent_squareWx = pointAx - 1; 
    var adjacent_squareWy = pointAy;

    var G = new Array(4); //cost of moving to given adjacent square
    var H = new Array(4); //cost of movimg to pointB from given adjacent square
    var F = new Array(4); //total cost of a move = G + H


    G[0] = 10; //N      
    G[1] = 10; //E      
    G[2] = 10; //S      
    G[3] = 10; //W


    H[0] = 10*(Math.abs(adjacent_squareNx-pointBx)+Math.abs(adjacent_squareNy-pointBy));        
    H[1] = 10*(Math.abs(adjacent_squareEx-pointBx)+Math.abs(adjacent_squareEy-pointBy));
    H[2] = 10*(Math.abs(adjacent_squareSx-pointBx)+Math.abs(adjacent_squareSy-pointBy));        
    H[3] = 10*(Math.abs(adjacent_squareWx-pointBx)+Math.abs(adjacent_squareWy-pointBy));


    F[0] = G[0]+H[0];       
    F[1] = G[1]+H[1];       
    F[2] = G[2]+H[2];
    F[3] = G[3]+H[3];

    var path = Math.min(F[0], F[1], F[2], F[3]); //WARPATH LOL

    //choosing the right path
    if (path == F[0])
    {
        //go N
        if (pointAy > 0) 
        {
            if (!(PS.BeadData(pointAx, pointAy - 1) === "blocked")) 
            {
                // Set bead to Previous State
                PS.BeadColor(pointAx, pointAy, Previous_bead_NPC[NPCid][2]);
                PS.BeadData(pointAx, pointAy, 0);
                PS.BeadGlyph(pointAx, pointAy, " ");                 
                // Increment
                pointAy -= 1;
                // Place NPC
                MakeNPC(pointAx, pointAy, NPC[NPCid][2], NPC[NPCid][3], NPC[NPCid][4], NPC[NPCid][5], 1);
            }
        }
    }
        else if (path == F[1])
            {
                //go E
                if (pointAx < 31) 
                {
                    if (!(PS.BeadData(pointAx + 1, pointAy) === "blocked")) 
                    {
                        // Set bead to Previous State
                        PS.BeadColor(pointAx, pointAy, Previous_bead_NPC[NPCid][2]);
                        PS.BeadData(pointAx, pointAy, 0);
                        PS.BeadGlyph(pointAx, pointAy, " ");                 
                        // Increment
                        pointAx += 1;
                        // Place NPC
                        MakeNPC(pointAx, pointAy, NPC[NPCid][2], NPC[NPCid][3], NPC[NPCid][4], NPC[NPCid][5], 1);
                    }
                }       
            }
                else if (path == F[2])
                    {
                        //go S
                        if (pointAy < 31) 
                        {
                            if (!(PS.BeadData(pointAx, pointAy + 1) === "blocked")) 
                            {
                                // Set bead to Previous State
                                PS.BeadColor(pointAx, pointAy, Previous_bead_NPC[NPCid][2]);
                                PS.BeadData(pointAx, pointAy, 0);
                                PS.BeadGlyph(pointAx, pointAy, " ");                 
                                // Increment
                                pointAy += 1;
                                // Place NPC
                                MakeNPC(pointAx, pointAy, NPC[NPCid][2], NPC[NPCid][3], NPC[NPCid][4], NPC[NPCid][5], 1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                        else if (path == F[3])
                            {
                                //go W
                                if (pointAx > 0) 
                                    {
                                        if (!(PS.BeadData(pointAx - 1, pointAy) === "blocked")) 
                                            {
                                                // Set bead to Previous State
                                                PS.BeadColor(pointAx, pointAy, Previous_bead_NPC[NPCid][2]);
                                                PS.BeadData(pointAx, pointAy, 0);
                                                PS.BeadGlyph(pointAx, pointAy, " ");                 
                                                // Increment
                                                pointAx -= 1;
                                                // Place NPC
                                                MakeNPC(pointAx, pointAy, NPC[NPCid][2], NPC[NPCid][3], NPC[NPCid][4], NPC[NPCid][5], 1);
                                            }
                                    }       
                            }


}

//checking if NPC has arrived
if (NPC[NPCid][4] == NPC[NPCid][0] && NPC[NPCid][5] == NPC[NPCid][1])
{
    NPC[NPCid][6] = 0;
}
else
{
    NPC[NPCid][6] = 1;
}                               
};
```

Comment: `Previous_bead_NPC` is a two dimensional array, where is the declaration/initialization of this `Array` object?

Comment: Maybe you should used objects with named properties rather then arrays where you have to remember which indexes mean which. Also replace your massive nested if with `r = Math.round(PS.Random(10)); switch (r) {case 0: ...}`.

Comment: And then make an `NPC` constructor with prototype methods. By the time you've finished re-writing it to be vaguely readable, this error will probably have gone away.

Comment: Gooby pls, I know I can't code. I don't even know what "prototype methods" are...

Answer (score 1):

`Previous_bead_NPC` is undefined, and thus not an object.
`Previous_bead_NPC[NPCid]` will also be undefined, when you get past that one.
You need to define these at some point (and presumably assign empty objects (`{}`) to them before attempting to access/assign their properties.

Comment: How would I define it as a not undefined type?

Comment: If you're going to post this much code and then not include the basics such as the definition of the variable that is referenced in your error, why do you expect any further help?

Comment: Define it as anything and it won't be undefined anymore :)

Comment: @OrangeDog because he has 1 point and has likely never used the site before.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can barely code as it is... I updated the OP with array declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm going to break the rules and post an off-topic CW answer.

You can use this bit of code...

```
var r = PS.Random (100),
    idx = Math.floor(r / 10);

NPC[NPCid][4] = locations[idx][0];
NPC[NPCid][5] = locations[idx][1];
```

---

...as a replacement for this entire chunk...

```
var r = PS.Random (100);

if (r < 10)
{
    NPC[NPCid][4] = locations[0][0];
    NPC[NPCid][5] = locations[0][1];
}
else if (r < 20)
    {
        NPC[NPCid][4] = locations[1][0];
        NPC[NPCid][5] = locations[1][1];
    }
    else if (r < 30)
        {
            NPC[NPCid][4] = locations[2][0];
            NPC[NPCid][5] = locations[2][1];
        }
        else if (r < 40)
            {       
                NPC[NPCid][4] = locations[3][0];
                NPC[NPCid][5] = locations[3][1];
            }
            else if (r < 50)
                {           
                    NPC[NPCid][4] = locations[4][0];
                    NPC[NPCid][5] = locations[4][1];
                }
                else if (r < 60)
                    {           
                        NPC[NPCid][4] = locations[5][0];
                        NPC[NPCid][5] = locations[5][1];
                    }
                        else if (r < 70)
                        {           
                            NPC[NPCid][4] = locations[6][0];
                            NPC[NPCid][5] = locations[6][1];
                        }
                            else if (r < 80)
                            {           
                                NPC[NPCid][4] = locations[7][0];
                                NPC[NPCid][5] = locations[7][1];
                            }
                                else if (r < 90)
                                {               
                                    NPC[NPCid][4] = locations[8][0];
                                    NPC[NPCid][5] = locations[8][1];
                                }
                                    else if (r < 100)
                                    {                   
                                        NPC[NPCid][4] = locations[9][0];
                                        NPC[NPCid][5] = locations[9][1];
                                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

before the row:

```
Previous_bead_NPC[NPCid][0] = x;
```

you have to define it will contain array:

```
Previous_bead_NPC[NPCid] = [];
```